# alternative to 'new Image()' of browser implementation into node-webgl javascript implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, canvas, browser

Currently I am using a webGL based browser implementation code at client end. It is working perfectly. But, I want to use the same code at server end. Yes, this is not browser based, pure javascript code using node-webgl library.

While doing thisI am facing a problem.

***new Image()*** is identified by browser, but at server side I am getting error Image is not defined. Below is the error I have attached. There are also additional two errors I am looking into it.

```
C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node>node exp.js
Status: Using GLEW 1.13.0
Linking ./simple.vert+./simple.frag
 ------------
Vertex info
-----------
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position

Linking ./raycast.vert+./raycast-color.frag
------------
Vertex info
-----------
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position

undefined:346
    gl.tf_img = new Image();
                    ^

ReferenceError: Image is not defined
at initTexture (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\exp.js:1
5:9), <anonymous>:346:18)
at volumerc_main (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\exp.js
:15:9), <anonymous>:392:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\exp.js:17:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:974:3
```

I tried another method installing canvas i.e npm install canvas and access it's Image object element: However, I am getting other error, looks like it is not compatible.  At start I have defined 
**var Canvas1 = require('canvas')
  , Image = Canvas1.Image;**

The error is below,

```
C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node>node exp.js
Status: Using GLEW 1.13.0
Linking ./simple.vert+./simple.frag
------------
Vertex info
-----------
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position

Linking ./raycast.vert+./raycast-color.frag
------------
Vertex info
-----------
(0) : error C5145: must write to gl_Position

C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\node-webgl\lib\webgl.js:806
  throw new TypeError('Expected texImage2D(number target, number level, numb
er internalformat, number format, number type, Image pixels)');
  ^

TypeError: Expected texImage2D(number target, number level, number     internalforma
t, number format, number type, Image pixels)
at Object.texImage2D (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\node-webgl
\lib\webgl.js:806:13)
at handleLoadedTexture (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\
exp.js:15:9), <anonymous>:330:5)
at gl.tf_img.onload (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\exp
.js:15:9), <anonymous>:349:3)
at Image.src (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\node_modules\canvas\lib\image.j
s:30:17)
at initTexture (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\exp.js:1
5:9), <anonymous>:351:16)
at volumerc_main (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\exp.js
:15:9), <anonymous>:392:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\z003npra\Desktop\node\exp.js:17:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

Any other alternative to imitate the Image type in node-webgl based implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Image from node-webgl library: `var Image = require("node-webgl").Image;`

Comment: And how to use Image from headless-gl library?